# how to design pseudo element in a div?

Tags: html, css

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.151);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding: 10px 40px;
}
.div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add the pseudo element of the div design to all four sides of the div it self with the same attriute of the border radius but it seems that i can only add the pseudo's to two sides using ::after and ::before.

Comment: What do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: I am not able to put images in my post yet but, when you run the code you will see that at the top left angle of the div is a pseudo element and i want that element to be on all four sides of the div each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add border to the div and use pseudo-classes `:before` & `:after` to mask edges.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffd8d8;
}

.div::after,
.div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffd8d8;
  z-index: -1;
}

.div::after {
  top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.div::before {
  top: 50%;
  left: -1px;
  height: 90%;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```